# jQuery load images and only display if load is complete

Tags: jquery

I have 4 div's which pick up images put on a web server taken from an FTP server feed from CCTV cameras.

At present, I have javascript in place to refresh these images every 3 seconds.

The nature of this process is that some of the frames are incomplete or faulty so they cause a broken image icon to appear for 3 seconds until the next refresh.

What I want to do is have a snippet of jQuery that loads the image into memory, checks that it's the dimensions we expect and that the image is properly formed, and then replace the image in the appropriate div once it passes those tests.

I haven't been able to work out how to load an image into memory to perform those checks, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onload event of the Image object to inspect their dimensions. Here's a function that uses this concept and should serve as a guide to solving your issue:

```
function setImageSize(image) {
    var defWidth = 240;
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
        var width, height;
        if (img.width > img.height) {
            width = (img.width > defWidth ? defWidth : img.width);
            height = img.height * (defWidth / img.width);
        } else {
            height = (img.height > 350 ? 350 : img.height);
            width = img.width * (350 / img.height);
        }
        img.width = width;
        img.height = height;
        img.src = image.src;
    }
}
```